# Best security practise for passing resource ID in URI

Tags: spring, rest, security, uri, microservices

I am currently working on developing Rest API for Bank. In Rest API principle URI are uniquely identify. That mean we have to pass the resource ID in request URL
eg:

- GET /customer/
- PUT /customer/
- DELETE /customer/

But problem is in my bank passing id's in URI prohibited due to security reason. (URI can read any one)

Could someone let me know is there any industry level best practise for overcome this security issue without violating Rest Resource naming principle?

Comment: Are you sure you're prohibited to put IDs in URIs? I understand they don't want you to pass any sensitive data like a session ID or a credit card number, that is indeed the best practice due to several reasons (request URLs getting logged on clients, proxies, also can be seen on the monitor sometime, etc.) But any resource ID in general? That would not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

> But problem is in my bank passing id's in URI prohibited due to security reason. (URI can read any one)

That is, if you're not using TLS/SSL which is anyway a no-go in security-critical environment like banking!! If somebody is able to read your request, he's able to read your HTTP-Traffic and thus there is no real way to protect anything sent over this wire reliably be that in the URL, in the headers or the content!

If you're not able to put anything in your URI you're gonna have a hard time developing clean and concise restfull HTTP APIs!

Comment: We using TLS/SSL. If it is so can you guarantee no security issue in passing ID's in url??

Comment: If done right; Sure! TLS encrypts all communication between HTTP endpoints, read up on TLS here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: But URL can be cash or save in browser history.

Comment: That A: depends on whether you actually navigate your browser (or you have a web-app that makes request to an API without navigating the browser) and B: if you do not trust the browser to be secure you have lost anyway!